# Unable to update my PATH variable in mac

Tags: php, path, phpunit, mamp

I am trying to install phpunit and in order to do that, I need to first set my machines php to point to my MAMP's php. So, I am trying to add my MAMP's php to my PATH variable.

I have tried adding

```
export PATH="/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.5.3/bin:$PATH"
```

to .bash_profile, .profile, .bashrc, /etc/path, but in the end, when I

```
echo $PATH
```

I still get the same PATH that I got before. And also, when i do

```
which php
```

I still get

```
/usr/bin/php
```

and yes, after changing the files, I do open a new terminal window.

Can someone help me out? What am I doing wrong or what am i missing?

Comment: make sure to restart your shell after changing the files.

Comment: are you sourcing your file after the edit in the terminal? `source ~/.profile`

Comment: omg, thanks a lot, I have been trying stuff for a few hours now and could not get it to work. source ~/.profile gave me this error /Users/admin/.profile:1: command not found: PATH. But when I tried source ~/.bash_profile, everything worked perfectly. Thanks a ton!

Answer (score 0):

Just in case anyone else gets stuck with the same question as me, here is what I was missing.

I just had to source my .bash_profile, like so

```
source ~/. bash_profile
```

This worked and my PATH was updated successfully!